# Redirect to full domain using tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I have a system that is running on tomcat 7, the user call it for example:

http://system1

Is there any way in tomcat to add the full domain name when the user call it like before?

from: http://system1 redirect or convert to: http://system1.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and I would like to share it, so after investigation it couldn't be done throw tomcat, but the developer can do it in his code, the solution in java e.g:

```
String reqURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
if (!reqURL.contains("domain.com")){
      response.sendRedirect("http://system1.domain.com");
}
```